# @typescript-eslint /parser vs /eslint-plugin

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint, typescript-eslintparser

It seems that [@typescript-eslint/parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/parser) and [@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin) are required to get ESLint properly working in TypeScript codebases.

How are they different? Why are they shipped separately if they are both required?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [Getting Started](https://typescript-eslint.io/getting-started/#details) guide:

> - `parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser'` tells ESLint to use the `@typescript-eslint/parser` package you installed to parse your source files.
>
>   - This is required, or else ESLint will throw errors as it tries to parse TypeScript code as if it were regular JavaScript.
> - `plugins: ['@typescript-eslint']` tells ESLint to load the `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` package as a plugin.
>
>   - This allows you to use typescript-eslint's rules within your codebase.

In short: the `eslint-plugin` package contains the actual lint rules, and the `parser` plugin adds support for parsing TypeScript files (ESLint on its own does not support TypeScript — it [used to](https://github.com/eslint/typescript-eslint-parser), but that project evolved into typescript-eslint).

Comment: What is the point of parsing TypeScript files if you don't also have the actual lint rules? Why are they shipped as two separate packages, if they are seemingly both necessary to get it working, and neither of them work as standalone packages? (or are the linting rules provided just extra rules and so not totally necessary?)

Comment: Teaching ESLint to parse TS files would allow the standard ESLint rules to run on TS code, in addition to any TS-specific rules. You can read more about parsers and why you'd want to configure one in the [ESLint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/parser). I can't answer "why" it was designed as two separate packages since I'm not part of that project — but probably just separation of concerns.